# Error accesing Azure FHIR Server metadata

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I deployed de Azure FHIR server from the Portal, following the steps listed on the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir-oss-portal-quickstart.

However, after all resources are created, I cannot retrieve metadata. I shows me the following error:
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable".

Can anyone tell me if I miss any step?

Comment: what is the query url of metafata that you are trying to access?

Comment: Can you provide the query you are trying to do? What kind of metadata?

Comment: The error message looks like you are trying the wrong URL, so for example if you did something like https://myfhirserver/MyResource you would get an error because there is no resource called MyResource in FHIR.